# Three.js TypeError: array[i] is undefined three.js:180:9 when using TransformControls

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js, transform, typeerror

I'm using Three.js TransformControls on loaded .STL Files, it work kinda nicely, but my console log me "TypeError: array[i] is undefined  three.js:180:9" each time i mouse hover or use the transformControls, does someone know why ? and how to fix it ? (as said it totally work but it's kinda annoying and bit non-professional).

Comment: Can you please post which version of three.js you're using? Also, any other debugging information you can provide (especially code, such as a link to your project, or a jsfiddle example) would be helpful.

Comment: Looking at the Threejs code at line 180, array[i] is referring to the THREE.EventDispatcher listeners. This likely means somewhere in the project is an event listener (addEventListener) where the object no longer exists and was never removed (removeEventListener.)

Comment: thanks man ! there was a TransformControls.addEventlistener ("change", renderer) who had no reason to live inhabiting my code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array[i] is referring to the THREE.EventDispatcher listeners.
There was a TransformControls.addEventlistener ("change", renderer) who had no reason to live inhabiting my code causing this error.